# Unity 3d client control of server scene

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I've searched for this for a while but I can't seem to find an answer. Here's my current state: i have a phone build of a scene which is the client and a pc build of a separate scene which is the server. I want the client scene to control the server scene. Image Jackbox TV but i'm not trying to use a web interface. I just want the phone to control the pc build. Every tutorial that I've searched through simply tells how to set up networking so that every instance of a player in a game is working in the same environment and getting all the correct variables. But I don't know how to send controls from one scene to the other. Can someone explain, even if it's just in "english code" how to do this? Something like

Add NetworkManager component to sceneA and sceneB
Setup functionA to pass variableA to functionB on sceneB

I'm not asking for an in depth coding lesson (although always appreciated), if someone could even give me the right things to google as are pertinent to my needs, even that would be wonderful.

Comment: Generally speaking servers are authoritative meaning that the server makes all calculations and notify all the clients. For your case, it sounds to me that you need a web service or web client to send commands. (Correct me if I am wrong)

Comment: no a traditional server that you've described is what i want. i want the server to do all the calculations, i just want those calculations to be triggered by phone controls. I know i mentioned jackbox tv in my description but that was just for conceptualizing the interaction i'm envisioning. I don't want anything running through web, just a server build of the game running one scene, and a client build running another scene that connects to the server and controls its functions with buttons on the phone

Comment: Then your question is wrong constructed. Anyway, all you need is a server running a scene and a client consuming that scene. I don't see the challenge here. Just google network manager to find tutorials. Nevertheless, you should start reading about general networking and learn how it works (7 levels of the OSI)

Comment: all of the tutorials that i've checked only tell you how to sync the SAME scene across all connected devices. i need to sync two different scenes